# Как выбрать посты между 2 полями и отсортировать по дате?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Как выбрать кастомные посты(project) у которых мета(area) между 100 и 150 и отсортировать по дате? Нужно просто выбрать дома у которых площадь между 100 и 150 и показывать сначала новые.

Решил для этого использовать фильтр posts_where.

```
function filter_area( $where = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;  
    $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'area' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value > 100  AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= 150)";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_area' );
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'project'));
```

Но запрос выдает ошибку

```
Ошибка базы данных WordPress: [Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_key' in 'where clause']
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'project' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'area' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value <= '100') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615634/wordpress-get-post-meta-within-posts-where-filter) задавали похожий вопрос, но у меня почему-то ругается на Unknown column, хотя все правильно.

wp_postmeta:
[image: wp_postmeta]
wp_posts:
[image: wp_posts]
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: по ходу решилось через wp_query. И sql не надо будет трогать

Answer (score 0):

Не знаком с wordpress к сожалению, но точно вижу, что в запросе вы делаете выборку из таблицы wp_posts, а колонка meta_key находится в таблице wp_postmeta. Поэтому ошибка неизвестной колонки вполне логична. Вам необходимо либо сделать подзапрос либо сделать join второй таблицы.